why my content is not showing between blockcontent and endblock in django?
i have build an other app in my django project and have a template in my templates folder and i am including the base.html from my other app

but the problem is in when i want to write html in my block content tags its showing it below the footer not in between the navbar and the footer
{% include 'webapp/base.html' %}

{% load static %}
{% block content %}
Patient Info
{% endblock %}
the screenshot is below

why i am getting this below my footer its working perfect in my firstapp in project all the other things like statics are loading but when i write anything in block tags its showing it in below the footer of my base.html this is happening only in my patients app not in webapp in webapp i also extending my base.html and its showing the block content in the block contents tag of base.html but in patients app its not showing inbetween the blockcontents

extend not include.

You extend a template, not include it, so use the {% extends … %} template tag [Django-doc]:
{% extends 'webapp/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
…
{% endblock %}

yes it fixed it but i learned from somewhere that when you have to extend your template from another app you should use include can you elaborate where to use include and where not

@MJunaid: include is when you use it as a sub-template, so fully copy a template (not fill in the blocks).
